# Autocompletion/Intellisense for React-native styles

Tags: react-native

What's the best way to  have auto completion (intellisense)  when defining styles?  Using the example below, it will be nice to have intellisense on available styles for titleStyles.

```
const styles = {
    titleStyles: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15
}};
```

Comment: Use Visual Studio Code

Comment: @HenrikR, I'm using VS code too.  Are you using flow or typescript to have intellisense for styling?

Comment: I have the same problem and nobody can solve it, either react native development on windows sucks or it is just editor that sucks.

Answer (score -4):

Use [ATOM](https://atom.io/) with [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) that is developed by facebook same origin of react-native [FacebookNuclide](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide)